# How to use Share in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am following the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android

To implement the share functionality in my Xamarin.iOS app. My code:

```
byte[] pdf = await DownloadPdfFile();

var fn = "myfile.pdf";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(file, pdf);

await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
    Title = ViewModel.Parameter.Title,
    File = new ShareFile(file)
});
```

Nothing happens when I run this code.

Comment: This should work, I have been using it for a while. Make sure its on MainThread

Comment: I wrapped it with `InvokeOnMainThread` and it still doesn't work. My colleague tested it on a physical device (iPad) and it doesn't work there either.

Comment: In the application output, I see the message "[ShareSheet] connection invalidated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. There is a bug when running on iPad as mentioned [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1247) and you can fix this by specifying the `PresentationSourceBounds`:

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
    Title = "My title",
    File = new ShareFile(file),
    PresentationSourceBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)View.Frame.Width, 0, (int)(View.Frame.Width), (int)(View.Frame.Height))
});
```

Comment: Consider marking it as answer to help others.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need to add some permissions in your info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery for saving photos and videos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos gallery for saving photos and videos.</string>
```

Let me know in case you have queries

Comment: Still doesn't work. I still get "[ShareSheet] connection invalidated" in the application output.

Comment: @Drake You never mentioned you were using an iPad lol